# Does SAX in perl have a parse_more function?

Tags: xml, perl, xml-parsing, sax

I am receiving XML data serially from an SSH2 connection in chunks of up to 16k. Every time I receive a chunk I simply pass it to the XML::Parser module via the parse_more function. This works really well. I was investigating switching over to use a SAX parser but I can't find a parse_more function. All the examples I've found use parse_uri or parse_string. I was hoping parse_string was the equivelant of parse_more but it requires the entire string in memory, largely defeating the purpose of using SAX. Does anyone know how to process data in chunks with SAX?

As an aside does anyone find perl module documentation to be extremely poor? In many cases they don't even at least list the available functions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [XML::Parser::PerlSAX](http://search.cpan.org/~kmacleod/libxml-perl-0.07/lib/XML/Parser/PerlSAX.pm)? It sounds like [it does not keep the whole document tree in memory](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2001/02/14/perlsax.html).

*[edit]* Instead, it uses a file handle to grab pieces of the XML. Maybe you could create a file-handle-like object for passing the chunks to XML::Parser?

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for the reply. That is the very reason I want to use SAX, so that we don't have to load the entire document in memory. The problem is I can't pass chunks of the document to the SAX parser.

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever find an answer? I asked a similar question earlier but have now stumbled on to `XML::SAX::Expat::Incremental` which seems to do exactly what we both need. It has the `parse_more` function, you just need to pass string chunks as you get them.

I haven't had time to test on a larger data set but initial tests work fine.